# When using this Container, bottom overflowed occured. Why?

Tags: flutter

When using last container, an error occured: bottom overflowed by 14 pixels

```dart
Container(
  height: 50,
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,

    children: [
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // Equal spacing
        children: [
          Text(" ${item.vchrName}"),
          Icon(IconlyLight.heart),

        ],
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // Equal spacing

        children: [
          Text("\$ ${item.dblSellingPrice}"),
          Icon(IconlyLight.chat),

        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
Container(
  height: 25,
  color:Colors.redAccent,

)
```

Comment: share the results you want to achieve and what are you getting from this code?

Answer (score 0):

Because the main `Container` has 50 fixed height, its child `Column` has 3 children, all their heights combined is exceeding above 50.
Remove the main container's height and add `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` to Column. So, it won't take more space than its children already has:

```
Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:
                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, 
                children: [
                  Text("Name"),
                  Icon(Icons.favorite),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:
                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                children: [
                  Text("\$ 123"),
                  Icon(Icons.chat),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                height: 25,
                color: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the height of the container.

Container(
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
children: [
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // Equal spacing
children: [
Text(" hello"),
Icon(Icons.add),

```
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, // Equal spacing

          children: [
            Text("\$ 20"),
            Icon(Icons.delete_forever),

          ],
        ),
        Container(
          height: 25,
          color:Colors.redAccent,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more of your code, as far as i can understand from the provided code is that you should wrap both Container inside Column, then wrap the Column with SingleSchildScrollView.

```
Scaffold(
 body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
   children: [
     Container(),
     Container()
   ]
  )
 )
)
```